# log4j not working from docker container

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, log4j

this is my log4j.xml content for a sample spring boot application:-

http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="generalLogFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<param name="AppenderImplementationClass" value="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" />
    <param name="FileBase" value="/app/info.log" />        
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %d{M/d/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="generalLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="errorLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

and I run the container using following command:-

docker run -it --rm --name testapp -v "/test/application/region/data/user/dockerlogs":/app testapp

logs are not getting written. I did docker inspect and can see that location is correctly mounted as /app inside container. I can even read files using /app/filename but log4j logs do not get written.

Comment: Did you check if the user running in the container has write access to the directory?

Comment: yes docker running with root id, I attached to container, did whoami it shows root and then I did mkdir newdir. and was able to create it. I still did chmod 777 on the mounted dir. so permissions look good

Comment: I guess my log4j xml was wrong, its solved by taking it from https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/